# Are express.compiler, app.error and app.address obsolete with Node.js 0.8.2 and Express.js 3.0.0beta6?

Tags: node.js, express

I just updated Node.js and bunch of modules to the latest, then I got plenty of errors. I tried to figure out and it seems some of stuff are undefined. Could anyone know what are the equivalents to these stuff?

Node.js version 0.8.2
Express.js version 3.0.0beta6
Connect.js version 2.3.8

```
express = require 'express'
app = express.createServer()
console.log express.compiler    # undefined
console.log app.error           # undefined
console.log app.address         # undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express is now a handler that you pass to http.createServer.

```
express = require 'express'
http = require 'http'
app = express()
( http.createServer app ).listen 3000
```

Comment: Oh, I gotcha. I've rolled back all the settings, so I can't test it right now, but that makes sense since I saw some of codes using `app=express()`. Hope there would be an official migration guide from 2.x to 3.x after beta removed like http://expressjs.com/migrate.html